# Understanding the use of Biztalk RFID

Tags: .net, nfc, biztalk, rfid, pcsc

I am a naïve in smart card industry. Recently I wrote an application to read and write the data on the proximity cards. I used the API (SDK) provided by the device manufacturer. Application worked very fine.

Then I came across the BizTalk RFID and PC/SC specification which I couldn't understand much.

> Why should I use BizTalk RFID to create RFID applications.
>
> Does BizTalk RFID follows PC/SC standards.

I am worried if I don't use these standards, would I be pushing myself in to application design troubles for a bigger application which requires the integration with devices from multiple manufacturers and different platforms.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used BizTalk RFID, and also not very familiar with the standards. I searched about it little bit and looks like BizTalk RFID fully support EPCIS standard, I am not if that's what you meant by PC/SC standards. some of the links to check out

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789456.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/krishg/archive/2009/03/26/biztalk-rfid-and-standards-support.aspx

hope it helps

Comment: I'd say PC/SC is short for "Personal Computer/Smart Card".  There are various devices out there that can read both smart cards and RFID tags.